# How to safely rename a class in Common project (shared by multiple solutions)

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, project-management, projects-and-solutions

I have a "Common" project shared by multiple solutions.

If I rename a class in the Common project, Visual Studio will refactor all code that uses that class, but on for the opened solution. Is it possible to force Visual Studio to refactor all solutions that use Common project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have a separate solution that included all projects that referenced it.