# How to programmatically add/remove exsting projects to a solution?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

A similar (not duplicate) question was posted at here: [How do I programmatically list all projects in a solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802027/reading-the-list-of-all-csproj-projects-of-solution-sln-programmatically)

In my previous question: [How to safely rename a class in Common project (shared by multiple solutions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304017/how-to-safely-rename-a-class-in-common-project-shared-by-multiple-solutions), [Thought](https://stackoverflow.com/users/117095/thought) suggested to create a separate solution to include all projects that reference my Common project.

So now I need to add/remove existing projects to my Common solution. I currently have about 50 projects reference the Common project, so it would be nice if I could programmatically add/remove projects from a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem...

Project.Remove() throws UnImplemented exception

the answer is to use:

[Solution::Remove(Project prj);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._solution.remove%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

and

[Solution::AddFromTemplate( string FileName, string Destination, string ProjectName, bool Exclusive)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._solution.addfromtemplate%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)